# insertar en una lista en prolog

Tags: lista, insert, prolog

tengo una lista dinámica en Prolog y necesito añadir elementos a esa lista de forma que todos los números que vaya introduciendo se queden en la misma lista para poder sumarlos despues.

```
dynamic lista/1.
lista([]).
```

Cuando inserto algún elemento con *assertz* se queda la lista de la siguiente forma:

```
?- assertz(lista(1)).
true.
?- assertz(lista(2)).
true.
?- assertz(lista(3)).
true.
?- lista(X).
X = [];
X = 1;
X = 2;
X = 3.
```

pero me gustaría poder insertar los números dentro de la primera lista

```
?- lista(X).
X = [1,2,3].
```

para después poder sumar los valores con la siguiente regla:

```
suma([], 0).
suma([H|T],Total) :- suma(T,A), Total is A + H.
```

```
?- suma(lista, Total).
Total = 6.
```

He intentado crear una regla inserta que me de una lista con todos los elementos que ya hay en la lista y el nuevo que queremos añadir y luego utilizar *assertz* pero no funciona.

```
inserta(X,Lista,[X|Lista]).
```

```
?- inserta(1, lista, NLista), assertz(lista(NLista)).
NLista = [1|lista].
?- lista(X).
X = [];
X = [1|lista].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:- dynamic lista/1.
lista([]).

inserta([],X,[X]).
inserta([H|T], N, [H|R]) :- inserta(T, N, R).
```

Con esta regla *inserta* podemos introducir un nuevo número en la lista utilizando el siguiente predicado:

```
nuevoNumero(Y):-lista(X), inserta(X, Y, Nueva), asserta(lista(Nueva)).
```

```
?- nuevoNumero(5).
true.

?- nuevoNumero(10).
true .

?- nuevoNumero(40).
true .

?- nuevoNumero(3).
true .
```

La lista se quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
?- lista(X).
X = [5, 10, 40, 3] .
```

Con esto ya conseguimos insertar el número dentro de la lista dinámica y podemos sumarlo utilizando la siguiente regla:

```
suma([], 0). 
suma([H|T],Total) :-suma(T,A), Total is A + H.
```

```
?- lista(X), suma(X, Total).
X = [5, 10, 40, 3],
Total = 58 .
```